# Removing N/A values from particular column in dataset

Tags: r

Apologies if this is a duplicate, I've searched high and low and cannot find something that works for me. I'm also quite new to R so hope I'm explaining myself correctly.

I have a dataset on video game data that looks like this

```
Game          Platform    Year of Release   Genre

Wii Sports    Wii          2006             Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          N/A              Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          2006             Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          N/A              Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          2006             Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          2006             Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          N/A              Sports
Wii Sports    Wii          2006             Sports
```

I'm trying to remove the rows with the N/A values from the Year of Release column. For a while I was trying things like na.omit() etc, but this did not work. I then realised the N/A is baked into the original .csv, so this could make R treat them as strings. I tried the grepl function then and this also did not work. Would anyone have any ideas?

If you need any further information let me know.

Thanks!

EDIT: The actual dataset is freely available here, I should probably have linked this originally:
https://www.kaggle.com/rush4ratio/video-game-sales-with-ratings?select=Video_Games_Sales_as_at_22_Dec_2016.csv

If anyone is able to remove the rows with N/A values from Year_of_Release column of this dataset and explain how they did it I would very much appreciate it, thanks again!

Comment: please provide the data as the output of `dput(mydata)`, so we get the same object / values you are using.

Comment: Try something like `df[df$year_of_release != 'N/A',]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the toy dataset created below as an example, I will show you how to subset your data to specific rows/observations on a logical condition.

```
df <- data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"), 
             year = c(2014, "N/A", 2015))
```

We can test whether each element of the variable `year` is not `N/A` using the not equal logical operator `!=`

```
df$year != "N/A"
```

That vector can be used to determine which rows of the data to return. That vector is expressed inside square braces as `i` of `df[i,j]`, where `i` determines the order or subset of observations in the data.frame `df` and `j` is the variables/columns to return (blank returns all variables).

```
df[df$year != "N/A", ]
```

Note that if your variable name (year of release) has spaces in it, you will need to wrap it in back ticks (```` ``` ````) and if you have actual `NA` values, use the `is.na()` function and the `!` operator to reverse the logic.

Comment: OP is dealing with `N/A` as strings

Comment: Well spotted thanks

Comment: I figured it out from this, thank you so much!

Comment: I don't have the reputation score to upvote but have accepted the answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

An elegant solution if you use the `tidyverse` that provides the method `drop_na` which is very intuitive to read. I just changed your variable to `Year_of_Release`

```
library(tidyverse)

data= data.frame("Game" = c("Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ","Wii Sports ","Wii Sports ","Wii Sports ","Wii Sports ","Wii Sports ","Wii Sports "),
                  "Platform" =c("Wii","Wii","Wii","Wii","Wii","Wii","Wii", "Wii"),
                  "Year_of_Release" = c(2006, NA, 2006, NA, 2006, 2006, NA, 2006),
                  "Genre"=c("Sports","Sports","Sports","Sports","Sports","Sports","Sports","Sports"))

data %>% drop_na("Year_of_Release")

           Game Platform Year_of_Release  Genre
1 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
2 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
3 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
4 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
5 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
```

or

```
data %>% drop_na(Year_of_Release) # if Year_of_Release is the column name
```

**Important** In R, `N/A` is not regarded as `NA` as suggested by `Lukasz.` Before attempting this, it should be converted to `NA`.

While reading the data with `read.table/read.csv`, use `na.strings` to specify the elements that will be `NA.`

```
 data<-read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = "N/A")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make `R` treat `"N/A"` string like actual `NA`:

```
mydata<-read.csv('file.csv', na.strings = c("N/A"))
```

and then use `na.omit()` as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I would first replace this "NA string" with actual NAs with `na_if`, then filter with `!is.na(variable)`

```
df %>% na_if("N/A") %>% filter(!is.na(Year_of_Release))

         Game Platform Year_of_Release  Genre
1 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
2 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
3 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
4 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
5 Wii Sports       Wii            2006 Sports
```

**data**

```
structure(list(Game = c("Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ", 
"Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports ", "Wii Sports "
), Platform = c("Wii", "Wii", "Wii", "Wii", "Wii", "Wii", "Wii", 
"Wii"), Year_of_Release = c("2006", "N/A", "2006", "N/A", "2006", 
"2006", "N/A", "2006"), Genre = c("Sports", "Sports", "Sports", 
"Sports", "Sports", "Sports", "Sports", "Sports")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```